# Facing parse error issue with google plusDomains rest api while creating post

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-plus, posts

I am using this link for creating posts on google plus - 
https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating

I have generated access token using these steps

1. Using the following link to generate code

   ```
   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me&approval_prompt=force&response_type=code
   ```

result

```
    {redirect_uri}/?code=4/OxhUqnNDDGPPcuf_VvE7cKuL4PXehuToUTfwyrt9U&authuser=0&prompt=consent&session_state=7da4522b3012e15uigggguhgue1bd80e6adb1bfd9..66de#
```

received this code "4/OxhUqnNDDGPPcuf_VvE7cKuL4PXehuToUTfwyrt9U" with redirect uri.

2. Using this code  I made a request for token at this url

   ```
   https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
   ```

post params -

```
    grant_type = authorization_code
    code = 4/OxhUqnNDDGPPcuf_VvE7cKuL4PXehuToUTfwyrt9U
    client_secret = {client_secret}
    redirect_uri = {redirect_uri}
    client_id = {client_id}
```

for which received following result

```
 {
"access_token": "{access_token}",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 3600,
"id_token": "{token_id}"
  }
```

Now when creating a post on google plus using the above access token in following curl request I get the parse error -

```
 curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer "{access_token}" -d "{"object": {"originalContent": "Happy Monday!#caseofthemondays"},"access":{"kind":"plus#acl","items":[{"type":"domain"}],"domainRestricted":true}}" -X POST https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/{user_id}/activities
```

Results -

```
  {
   "error": {
     "errors": [
       {
         "domain": "global",
         "reason": "parseError",
         "message": "Parse Error"
       }
    ],
     "code": 400,
   "message": "Parse Error"
   }
 }
```

There is no description for this error code at the following link -
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors

And using both these permissions

```
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write
```

As suggested by mahendar it does solves the parse error which I figured earlier today. But now I am facing the following issue of

```
  {
    "error": {
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "reason": "forbidden",
          "message": "Forbidden"
        }
      ],
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Forbidden"
    }
  }
```

I guess the permissions are wrong. I have enabled the domainPlus api in developers console.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

`curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}" -d '{"object": {"originalContent": "Happy Monday!#caseofthemondays"},"access":{"kind":"plus#acl","items":[{"type":"domain"}],"domainRestricted":true}}' -X POST "https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/activities"`

Comment: Yes it does solves the parse error , but now the issue is 403 Error

Comment: To create an activity you must have  google domain account credentials.